# JITWatch assembly code generation

Tags: java, jit

I am trying to use JITWatch to see how assembler code corresponds to original Java source code. However, JITWatch does not seem to see my assembly code and prints the following message:

> Assembly not found. Was -XX:+PrintAssembly option used?

I am using Oracle's JRE 1.8.0_121 on Windows 10 Home. I've added dissembly dll's to my JRE. The dll's were downloaded from [FCML project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fcml/files/). I can confirm that assembly is generated when I run program with `java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions  -XX:+PrintAssembly test.Test` options.

I've configured JITWatch paths so that *.java and *.class files are visible to it. For JITWatch analysis I run my Java program with `java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+LogCompilation -XX:+PrintAssembly test.Test` and open the generated .log file with JITWatch. It can see the Java code and bytecode, but not the assembly. I suspect the problem is caused by the fact that assembly is printed to standard output (to the console) and not to log file. Is there an option I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch/issues/256) that occured when JITWatch was used together with FCML dissassembler. Thanks to prompt reaction by program developer it is fixed now.